# Pass multiple query parameters to WebService via PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I am calling webservice GET method via PowerShell like so:

```
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://localhost/MyApi/Foo/blahA/blahB?three=testing&four=2015-09-18T06:45:29.5199432Z
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
>   quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
>
> - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed

If it matters here is my WebAPI code and routing (the method has two required parameters, and 3 optional):

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("Foo")]
public string Foo(string one, string two, 
       string three = null, DateTime? four = null, int five = null)
{
    //do stuff
    //return some string
}
...
routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "Foo",
           routeTemplate: "Foo/{one}/{two}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Testing", action = "Foo" }
           );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couple of things, you should wrap your URI in double-quotes:

```
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://localhost/MyApi/Foo/blahA/blahB?three=testing&four=2015-09-18T06:45:29.5199432Z"
```

Second, your url looks wrong in general, try

```
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://localhost/MyApi/Foo?one=blahA&two=blahB&three=testing&four=2015-09-18T06:45:29.5199432Z"
```